# Azure DevOps replace part of variable with value from KeyVault

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have a Azure Devops pipeline that tries to replace part of a string variable value with a value from Azure KeyVault.

Given a KeyVault secret `kvSecret` with value `this-is-my-secret`, I want another variable `foo` with value `this-is-your-secret`.

```
jobs:
- job: WebApp
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  variables:
    foo: $[replace(variables['kvSecret'], 'my', 'your')]

  steps:
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'foo'
      KeyVaultName: 'myKeyVault'
      RunAsPreJob: true
```

Since logging is masked, I tested this by writing to a file:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        New-Item $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\test.txt
        Set-Content $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\test.txt '$(foo)'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

The output is `this-is-my-secret` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your YAML definition, the variable foo should be empty.

The reason for this issue is that the replace expression will be expanded at compile time.

And the variable in your Key Vault will be downloaded when the pipeline is running.

Therefore, when the replace operation is performed, the kvSecret variable is empty, and the foo variable is also empty.

In order to solve this issue, you need to add a script to the Agent Job to perform the replace operation.

Here is an example:

```
jobs:
- job: WebApp
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    
  steps:
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'xx'
      KeyVaultName: 'xx'
      SecretsFilter: '*'
      RunAsPreJob: true

  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $newvalue = "$(kvSecret)" -replace "my", "your"
        echo $newvalue 
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=foo]$newvalue"
        
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo "$(foo)"
        New-Item $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\test.txt
        Set-Content $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\test.txt -value '$(foo)'
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Result:

[image]